# CSS File not working in spring application

Tags: html, css, spring, visual-studio-code

I'm currently working on a Spring project with classmates. I'm working on the frontend.

I'm mainly using Bootstrap, but because I wanted do add other features, I added a CSS file that I "linked" to my HTML file :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Uber Ritz</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="menuMidi.css">
```

It's working with no problems when I check my html page from my own documents, but once I try to run the whole application on vscode, my website has no css arguments (it's like the css file doesn't exist.

Does anyone ever had the same problem ? Is there something to add in the  segment ?

Thanks :)

Comment: you can't run HTML on VSC, it is an editor and HTML can't be run, what exactly do you try

Comment: It's a whole spring project. I'm trying to run an Application.java file